# How to call functions from html code using express-handlebars?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I´m sure this is a very basic question, but I´m starting with MEAN stack using `express-handlebars` and still launching my skills.

I´m coming from PHP world and I use to call PHP functions from insede my `phtml` code, as:

```
   <p>&copy; 2012 - <?= date('Y') ?> by ACME LLC. All rights reserved.</p>
```

That would get me the current year and print the following output:

**(C) 2012 - 2016by ACME LLC. All rights reserved.**

I know handlebars `{{ }}` would print any context variable, but don´t want to put the current year in the conetext to be printable.

I´ve seen also handlebars helpers, but I´m not sure this is the way to go.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you can call a function from html code but you can set helpers to run on server side as well as client side.

```
var register = function(Handlebars) {

    var helpers = {
        // put all of your helpers inside this object
        foo: function(){
            return "FOO";
        },
        bar: function(){
            return "BAR";
        }
    };

    if (Handlebars && typeof Handlebars.registerHelper === "function") {
        // register helpers
        for (var prop in helpers) {
            Handlebars.registerHelper(prop, helpers[prop]);
        }
    } else {
        // just return helpers object if we can't register helpers here
        return helpers;
    }

};

// client
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    register(Handlebars);
}
// server
else {
    module.exports.register = register;
    module.exports.helpers = register(null);
}
```